# Are explicit encapsulating delegates still preferred for events in C#?

Tags: c#, events, delegates

Style question.

The C# 1.0 way to subscribe to an event is to use an explicit encapsulating delegate:

```
publisher.RaiseCustomEvent += new CustomEventHandler(HandleCustomEvent);
```

In C# 2.0 they added a simpler syntax:

```
publisher.RaiseCustomEvent += HandleCustomEvent;
```

In Visual Studio 2010 (tested with a .NET 3.5 project) typing

```
"myObject.SomeEvent +="
```

brings up the option to hit tab to fill in the explicit delegate.
Furthermore, code created with the WinForms designer always uses explicit delegates.

I understand the value in being explicit, but not at the sacrifice of readability.  Given that the new syntax is much simpler/cleaner/readable and has been around since 2006, why does Visual Studio push you so hard into using the old syntax?   Is it still the preferred syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the designer code, it *should* stick with the explicit delegate creation. Both methods (implicitly-typed delegates and explicitly-typed delegates) result in the same IL; the implicit typing is just a language feature in C#, so there's no particular reason for the designer to try to take advantage of them.

As for the typeahead feature when attaching to an event, I have no explanation for that. The only time (I'm aware of) that requires explicit delegate creation is when the target is of type `Delegate` (meaning that it has no formal signature). Since you can only declare an event that's of a specific delegate type, I see nothing other than choosing to prioritize other IDE features above this as a reason for this to remain.

Answer (score 0):

There's no good reason.  I always remove them.  Suit yourself, though I agree with any tendency you have to remove them!